# What should be the best way to load setting from Database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

how should i load the table "Setting" into an asp.net mvc so that i can use it as a reference setting for the whole application.

Is there anyway to save the memory and usage to do this problem? In my understanding, if i have settings in database, i will have to make the program load the table into a variable, then call out. But is there anyway to save a query from being waste?

im using linq to sql

Thanks

Comment: You need to save the settings somewhere, so what "waste" are you afraid of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you use a proper ORM layer, like NHibernate (for instance with Fluent), which can cache the calls (SQL queries) to the settings table for you fully automatically. And you'll handle the tables without any SQL, only as calls to methods of classes.

However, it requires learning NHibernate, which can take a bit getting used to.

It is not possible to get the data of the Settings table from the database without issuing a query to the database. But you can prevent the tedious use of mapping the result to objects by using an ORM.

If you take both [NHibernate](http://nhibernate.org) and [FluentNHibernate](http://fluentnhibernate.org), it looks something like this for MS SQL Server 2008:

```
// this depends on your implementation, I assume a Settings class with 
// simple getters and setters that map directly to the table. Use 
// Fluent to do the mapping (see link) automatically through AutoMappings

// example of using AutoMappings plus configuration of linking to DB:
ISessionFactory sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(
        MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
            .ConnectionString(c =>
                c.Server("123.12.21.321")
                .Database("db_name")
                .Username("db_user_with_access_to_db")
                .Password("passwordhere")
                )
    )
    .Mappings(m =>
        m.AutoMappings.Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Logo>()
            .Where(t => t.Namespace == "YourNamespace.Entities"))
        )
    .BuildSessionFactory();

// example of a Settings class:
public class Settings
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public int BackgroundColor { get; set }
    // etc
}



// example of getting a session, retrieving data, changing/saving data
ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();  // session for getting data from DB
Setting mySetting = session.Get<Setting>(someId);
mySetting.BackgroundColor = 0xAA44DD;
var transaction = session.BeginTransaction();
session.SaveOrUpdate(mySetting);
transaction.Commit();

// how it looks like if you use Generics and a little Dao class to wrap it all up:
Dao<Settings> daoSettings = new Dao<Settings>(); 
Settings someSettings = daoSettings.Get(someIdHere);
Settings userSettings = daoSettings.Get(new User("John"));
List<Settings> allSettings = daoSettings.GetAll();

int BackgroundColor = userSettings.BackgroundColor;  // any of the columns here
userSettings.BackgroundColor = 0x45DA8E;
daoSettings.Save(userSettings);
```

Other ORMs exist, NHibernate may be a bit overkill if this is a one-time only situation and if you never did this before. However, it has an automatic level-1 and level-2 cache to prevent any unnecessary roundtrips to the database. It is currently (allegedly?) the industry leading open source ORM solution.

***Update:*** added simple code example and links to NH/Fluent